# How to sum multiple rows based on condition and put the result into another columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find rows in dataframe that have center = 1000 and element in range (10,20). After finding these rows, I want to copy values for them from columns ["1","2","3"] and put them as a one row, where center = 1000 and element = 89 in columns ["1C", "2C", "3C"].

I have tried below code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
df.loc[(df["center"] == 1000) & (df["element"] >= 10) & (df["element"] <= 20), ["1C", "2C", "3C"]] = df.loc[ (df["center"] == 1000) & (df["element"] == 89), ["1", "2", "3"]].sum().values
```

It doesn't give any error because it's part of a function, but I don't understand why wouldn't it work.

Here is example dataset:

```
0   center  element 1   2   3   1C  2C  3C
1   1000    11  30  30  30  0   0   0
2   1000    12  70  70  70  0   0   0
3   1000    89  0   0   0   0   0   0
4   1001    11  5   5   5   0   0   0
5   1002    12  6   7   8   0   0   0
```

Here is desired output:

```
0   center  element 1   2   3   1C  2C  3C
1   1000    11  30  30  30  0   0   0
2   1000    12  70  70  70  0   0   0
3   1000    89  0   0   0   100   100   100
4   1001    11  5   5   5   0   0   0
5   1002    12  6   7   8   0   0   0
```

Comment: can you show us an example of your initial dataframe and the expected result?

Comment: Can you copy paste part of your df here?

Comment: I have updated to show dataframes and desired output. @PedroRocha

Answer (score 0):

You can get that result doing this to your dataframe:

```
target_rows = df.loc[(df["center"] == 1000) & (df["element"].between(10, 20))]
df.loc[(df["center"] == 1000) & (df["element"] == 89), ["1C", "2C", "3C"]] = target_rows[["1", "2", "3"]].sum().values
```